# How to get a valid RS256 token from Azure in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm doing a Flutter app for iOS and Android, and I need to use authentification to access to the main content.

For that I used [this pubdev package](https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth)(aad_oauth), and it works very well. I need to get the token provided by Azure to send it to my API to authenticate my user.

I used this method :

```
    var token = await oauth.getAccessToken();
```

But the token is considered invalid even by my API then by https://jwt.io/ with the error "invalid signature" but works in the Flutter app.

Here is a censored screen of jwt.io :

[image]

Did someone knows how to get a valid token to send it after ?

Answer (score 0):

The invalid signature thrown by jwt.io is well known. You will need to manually obtain and set the Azure AD signing certificate content. Follow the steps detailed in [USING JWT.IO TO VERIFY THE SIGNATURE OF A JWT TOKEN.](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/03/using-jwt-io-to-verify-the-signature-of-a-jwt-token/)

Regarding validation at the API, you may have to fine-tune its token validation routine. This varies depending on the platform or library used for such end. you can find samples for Microsoft backed libraries [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-api).

For more information on recommended validation please take a look to [Validate tokens.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validate-tokens)

Comment: I checked your link, it seems good but the token kid and the kid in the discovery/keys isn't the same